# VsCode não reconhece biblioteca

Tags: python, pandas

Sou iniciante e vou começar a usar a biblioteca **pandas**.
Digitei no meu CMD:

```
pip install pandas
```

e aparentemente tudo funcionou legal.
Mas estou tentando usar a biblioteca e me devolve este erro:

```
    import pandas as pd
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

Ao digitar  `-c "import pandas; print(pandas.__version__)"`
tenho isso devolvido: `2.0.0`

Por fim: Uma imagem ao usar o comando `pip show pandas`
[inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBWhL.png)

Comment: Poderia dar mais detalhes, como caso estiver duas versões do python, se tem ambientes virtuais. esse tipo de detalhe pode melhorar

Comment: Aparentemente eu tenho 2 versions. Digitei no CMD, ```where python`` e me retornou isso:
```
C:\Users\Riquelme>where python
C:\Users\Riquelme\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe
C:\Users\Riquelme\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe`
``

Comment: Então sua lib, foi parar em uma delas e por casualidade o vscode pegou logo a que não estava instalada 

Comment: Qual forma mais simples de resolver? Desinstala um Python? Ou tem alguma forma específica de instalar?

Comment: Nao precisa desinstalar, Só tem que identificar  qual é a versão esta as libs que instalou e  mudar o compilador do python no vscode. sabendo qual é o python padrão vai ser tranquilo.

Answer (score -3):

Opa, como você está rodando seu código python? pelo próprio vscode?
O seu vs code reclama da lib? Se não você pode ver qual interpretador ele está usando, na parte inferior direita da IDE
[inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CVSt.png)

- Caso ele esteja reclamando você pode clicar onde mostra a versão e tentar trocar pelas opções [inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VqKnd.png) Ele vai mostrar vários interpretadores, você pode ir testando até achar qual o seu código está rodando.
- também verificar se não tem 2 pythons instalados, na sua maquina se for pelo cmd tenta rodar o código, usando  python [nome do arquivo] ou python3 [nome do arquivo].
- pode ser que estava usando ambiente virtual e não percebeu.